# How can I group my data frame based on conditions on a column

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame like this:

| Date | Version | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 123.1 | 3 | A |
| Jan 2 | 123.23 | 5 | A |
| Jan 1 | 223.1 | 6 | B |
| Jan 2 | 623.23 | 7 | B |

I want to group the table for 'Version' with the same prefix (everything from the first letter to there is the `.`. And for the `Value`, it selects the values using the row with the longest string length of version.  And for the `Name' column, it uses any of the rows with the same prefix.

| Version Prefix | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 5 | A |
| 223 | 6 | B |
| 623 | 7 | B |

Meaning version 123.1 and 123.23 has the same prefix '123', so both rows become  1 row in the result.  And 'Value' equals to 5 since row with Version 123.23 (the row with the longest
Version has 5 as Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (df.withColumn('Version Prefix', split('Version','\.')[0])#Create new column
 .withColumn('size', size(split(split('Version','\.')[1],'(?!$)')))#Calculate the size of the suffixes
 .withColumn('max', max('size').over(Window.partitionBy('Version Prefix','Name')))#Find the suffix with the maximum size
 .where(col('size')==col('max'))#Filter out max suffixes
 .drop('Date','size','max','Version')#Drop unwanted columns
).show()

+-----+----+--------------+
|Value|Name|Version Prefix|
+-----+----+--------------+
|    5|   A|           123|
|    6|   B|           223|
|    7|   B|           623|
+-----+----+--------------+
```